# Horizontal FlatList React Native with different height of items

Tags: react-native, layout, react-native-flatlist

I have a little problem with the FlatList Component in react native. In the FlatList are items with different height. Here is a little example of what i have:

[example FlatL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55jnS.gif)

The first problem is that all items are positioned at the top. I want to position all items at the bottom.

The second problem is that the height of the FlatList is always the height of the biggest item. So you can also scroll to another item in the white area of a small item...

here my code:

```
    import React from "react";
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    ListView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Animated,
    Image,
    FlatList
} from "react-native";

import glamorous, { ThemeProvider } from "glamorous-native";

import theme from "../theme";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

const cards = [
    {
        id: 1,
        color: "red",
        height: 400
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        color: "blue",
        height: 300
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        color: "yellow",
        height: 200
    }
];

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ bottom: 0 }}>
                <FlatList
                    ref={elm => (this.flatList = elm)}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={cards}
                    pagingEnabled={true}
                    horizontal={true}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View
                            style={{
                                height: item.height,
                                width: width,
                                backgroundColor: item.color
                            }}
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Has anyone a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of each item by setting the `contentContainerStyle` property of the `FlatList` itself. But the height of the FlatList will always have to be the height of the largest component inside it.

Comment: yeah i found this property too. I can set the position of the flatlist items to bottom: 0 but the flatlist is to height and you can swipe to next item in the white area of a small item...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with onViewableItemsChanged prop

```
viewabilityConfig={{itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50}}
onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}


onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {
    let index = viewableItems[0].index;
    this.setState({ indexOfImages: index,  heightOfImages: SCREEN_WIDTH * (viewableItems[0].item.height / viewableItems[0].item.width) });
}
```

We have width and height of the items in its data so I'm taking width and height of the visible item on the screen and do some calculations and I'm using *this.state.heightOfImages* in flatlist height like this

```
height: this.state.heightOfImages == undefined ? SCREEN_WIDTH * (images[0].height / images[0].width) : this.state.heightOfImages
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap the content of each card in another `<View>` element with `styles={{ minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 300 }}` and it will work fine!